# in java, is it possble to name an array from a string?

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginner with java, and I was wondering is if is possible to name and create an array from the value of a string.

Here is what I have:

```
public static void array(){

    createArray(array1, 100, 100);
}

    public static void createArray(String name, int r, int c) {
            int[][] name = new int[r][c];
}
```

I hope that explains itself. Thanks

EDIT: The code above does not work. I just want to know if it is possible to do what is above

EDIT2: As a beginner with java, I am just watching tutorials, and creating programs with what I learned to make sure I understand what is being taught. I first created a program which creates s multidimensional arrays. It then calls a method which assigned values to the array, (row+1)*(column+1). This makes a table much like a multiplication table. Then it displays the table to the screen.

After I created that program, I wanted to be able to create arrays much like I assigned the values to it. So i asked this question...

Here is my code:

```
 public static void array(){
   int[][] array1 = new int[100][100];
   int[][] array2 = new int[20][20];

   setArrayValue(array1);
   setArrayValue(array2);
   drawArray(array1);
   System.out.println();
   drawArray(array2);
}  

public static void setArrayValue(int x[][]){
   for(int row = 0; row<x.length; row++){
       for(int column=0; column<x[row].length; column++){
           x[row][column]= (column+1)*(row+1);
        }
    }      
}

public static void drawArray(int x[][]){
    for(int row=0; row<x.length; row++) {
        for(int column=0; column<x[row].length;column++){
            System.out.print(x[row][column] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? There might be better alternative

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with such a construction? How do you want to access your array? In the first place the array does not have a name but is references by a static name.

Answer (score 8):

Your concept doesn't make sense.

You might want to use a `Map<String, int[][]>`, which will map names to arrays.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not possible in Java.  In the `createArray` method, `name` is of type `String` and cannot be redeclared as an `int` array.

Perhaps you are interested in a [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that uses `String` objects as keys?  The values could be `int` arrays (or any other object).

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that.

Variable names are not variable in Java.

Furthermore, local variables even lose their names when the code is compiled. Variable names are just a help for the programmer to distinguish between variables.

Answer (score 1):

Nop can't be done. Variable names need to be known before hand.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You might be able to accomplish your task with a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) or another [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) implementation instead.

Instead of saying

```
 name = something;
```

You would say

```
  map.put(name, something);
```

Instead of

```
  name[0] + 7
```

You'd say

```
  map.get(name)[0] + 7
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others - this cannot be done. That is because Java compiler needs to know exact name of a variable at the compile time. This is mandatory, since otherwise Java compiler wouldn't know which variable you are addressing, so it couldn't perform, for instance, type-safety checks.

However, if you just wish to stamp your variable with some unique ID, I guess the solution is closest to what has been stated by SLaks. Simply use Map, and You should be good. Example below.

```
Map<String, int[][]> myMap = new HashMap<String, int[][]>();
myMap.put("someUniqueName", new int[][] {{0,0}, {1,1}});
```

and later on:

```
int[][] array = myMap.get("someUniqueName");
```

Hope that helps achieve what You want.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly: almost ;-) You can add a dynamic field in a class, which could be an array, using AOP. But...

It's difficult.

This solution is too complicated in most cases. You could probably solve your real problem in a much easier way.

Some advice: start with the beginning... and try using List (interface) / ArrayList as much as possible unless you have some pretty good reason to use an array.